# Downloading and resizing an image with Axios/Sharp

Tags: node.js, axios, sharp

I'm currently trying to download an image using Axios and then resize the result and save it locally via Node in a GraphQL resolver.

This is the block of code I'm working with:

```
axios.get(url)
    .then((response) => {
        const { set, collector_number } = response.data;
        const sourceUrl = response.data.image_uris.border_crop;
        const filename = `${set}/${collector_number}.png`;
        axios.get(sourceUrl, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' })
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(`Resizing Image!`)
                sharp(res)
                    .resize(226, 321)
                    .toFile(`../cardimg/${filename}`)
                    .then(() => {
                        console.log(`Image downloaded and resized!`)
                    })
                    .catch((err) => {
                        console.log(`Couldn't process: ${err}`);
                    })
            })
    })
```

When I execute the code (via GraphQL Mutation), it throws an error saying that states: `Input file is missing`.

Not sure if it's misuse of Axios, or if I'm doing something wrong with Sharp.

Any suggestions? I was originally worried that I needed to mess with the format of the response coming from the HTTP request, but from what I can gather, I'm doing it correctly.

Thanks in advance!

I've used console.log to ensure that it's definitely grabbing an image and the URL is correct, so that's already been tested, so the sourceUrl is indeed grabbing an image, I'm just not sure how to properly do anything -with- the data that I'm grabbing.

Comment: can you change the `sharp(res)` to `sharp(res.data)`? Because `res` contains whole lot of other keys other than data. Like header and such

Comment: If that doesn't work try `sharp(new Blob([res.data],  { type: 'image/png'}))` and check

Comment: It was definitely because I wasn't using `.data` in the second request!   If you make this a solution, I'll accept, was an oversight on my part.   Thanks!

Comment: Added as answer, also chained the promise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`axios` returns full response body like `status`, `headers`, `config`. The response body is in `.data` key. So in your case it will be:

```
axios.get(..).then((res) => { sharp(res.data)})
```

Also, Promises inside promises are considered anti pattern, you can chain it easily.

```
let fileName;
axios.get(url)
  .then((response) => {
    const { set, collector_number } = response.data;
    const sourceUrl = response.data.image_uris.border_crop;
    filename = `${set}/${collector_number}.png`;
    return axios.get(sourceUrl, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' })
  })
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(`Resizing Image!`)
    return sharp(res.data)
      .resize(226, 321)
      .toFile(`../cardimg/${filename}`)
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log(`Image downloaded and resized!`)
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(`Couldn't process: ${err}`);
  })
```

Comment: I actually was unaware of this being true, and for some reason (I'm still learning Promises), I didn't know you could chain them like that.   Thanks a ton!   Accepted!